# Recursively applying dollar_format to get dollar format in a list

Tags: r, dplyr

I am a beginner in R. So, I am sorry if this is too easy for some of you. I have a list, and I want to convert one of the columns ("Value") to dollar format. I'd appreciate any help.

I tried `lapply()` without any success.

Here's my data:

```
dput(Input_File)
structure(list(Zone = c("East", "East", "East", "East", "East", 
"East", "East", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West"), Fiscal.Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018), Transaction.ID = c(132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 171, 171, 172, 173, 175, 176, 177, 178
), L.Rev = c(30000, 20000, 23400, 23423, 2344, 452343, 23445, 
234, 45234, 23, 234345, 43534, 23421, 345345), L.Qty = c(234253, 
2342, 12334, 234253, 2342, 12334, 234253, 2342, 12334, 234234, 
223423, 234234, 43534, 432423), A.Rev = c(17253, 11117, 19751, 
10457, 11820, 14607, 14512, 16676, 12189, 11714, 12243, 18506, 
10500, 17793), A.Qty = c(19245, 17584, 18267, 19371, 19867, 13359, 
16932, 11541, 13434, 14409, 13908, 11042, 14632, 17332), I.Rev = c(17775, 
14452, 18459, 19481, 18463, 16566, 11749, 19208, 12244, 15344, 
15561, 16261, 11977, 11643), I.Qty = c(16441, 10409, 14249, 11737, 
11439, 11714, 18159, 18523, 17653, 14573, 16571, 13127, 12152, 
12692)), .Names = c("Zone", "Fiscal.Year", "Transaction.ID", 
"L.Rev", "L.Qty", "A.Rev", "A.Qty", "I.Rev", "I.Qty"), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my code:

```
Output<-Input_File %>%
gather(Rev_Qty,Value, L.Rev:I.Qty)  %>%
separate(Rev_Qty, into=c("L.A","Rev.Qty")) %>% 
split(.,list(.$Zone,.$Rev.Qty,.$Fiscal.Year),drop = TRUE) %>%
lapply(.,function(x) {scales::dollar_format()(.[6])})
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("round_any") : 
  no applicable method for 'round_any' applied to an object of class "list"
```

**Expected output:**
I don't know how to create a list with the output I want because I don't know how to apply dollar_format() recursively, but here's what I can say: it would be such that after running the following code:

```
Output<-Input_File %>%
    gather(Rev_Qty,Value, L.Rev:I.Qty)  %>%
    separate(Rev_Qty, into=c("L.A","Rev.Qty")) %>% 
    split(.,list(.$Zone,.$Rev.Qty,.$Fiscal.Year),drop = TRUE)
```

the numbers in column "Value" of each of the 10 data frames in the list `Output` would be represented in $ format. The output must be a list of 10 data frames. For instance, here's the code to show you how the sixth column (Value) of the first dataframe in a list will look like:

```
a<-Output[[1]]$Value
scales::dollar_format()(a)
```

In each data frame of the `Output` list, there would be other columns as usual. I'd appreciate any help. Please let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using the anonymous function call, use the `x[[6]]` instead of `.[6]`

```
Input_File %>%
     gather(Rev_Qty,Value, L.Rev:I.Qty)  %>%
     separate(Rev_Qty, into=c("L.A","Rev.Qty")) %>% 
     split(.,list(.$Zone,.$Rev.Qty,.$Fiscal.Year),drop = TRUE) %>%
     lapply(.,function(x) {x[[6]] <- scales::dollar_format()(x[[6]])
                   x})
```

---

Or without the anonymous call with `map` (from `purrr`)

```
library(purrr)
Input_File %>%
      gather(Rev_Qty,Value, L.Rev:I.Qty)  %>%
      separate(Rev_Qty, into=c("L.A","Rev.Qty")) %>% 
      split(.,list(.$Zone,.$Rev.Qty,.$Fiscal.Year),drop = TRUE) %>%
       map(~mutate(., Value = scales::dollar_format()(Value)))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. Could you please explain the use of "x" on the second line of `lapply`? I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @watchtower By using the anonymous fucntion, the 'x' is the data.frame inside the list. x[[6]] is the 6th column.  We have to return the values of 'x' after the assignment

Comment: Thanks for your help. Final question: if 'x' is the data.frame inside the list, why did we use x[[6]] to get the 6th column and not x[6]? For instance, if I do: (assuming the list is `Output`), `a <- Output[[1]]`, wouldn't I have a data frame in `a`, and if so, I would just use a[6] to access the 6th column. I'm a little confused. I'd sincerely appreciate your guidance in your answer so that it is clear to newbies like me.

Comment: @watchtower x[[6]] returns a vector similar to `x[,6]`, while `x[6]` is still a datafame.  If you replace `x[[6]]` with `x[6]`, you will get the error `Error in UseMethod("round_any") : 
  no applicable method for 'round_any' applied to an object of class "data.frame"`  Most of the functions work on a vector rather than a dataframe